# Adding custom discount adds 2 times in EE 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, discount

I am adding custom discount to my cart but it seems it is adding 2 times in the cart.

Here is my model file code.

```
$discount = 10;
$baseDiscount = 10;

$total->addTotalAmount('plandiscount', -$discount);
$total->addBaseTotalAmount('plandiscount', -$baseDiscount);
$total->setPlanDiscount(-$discount);
$total->setBasePlanDiscount(-$baseDiscount);
$quote->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() - $discount);
$quote->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() - $baseDiscount);

$quote->setPlanDiscount(-$discount);
$quote->setBasePlanDiscount(-$baseDiscount);
```

It is really strange that if the value is positive, it is working fine but in case of negative, it is adding 2 times.

Comment: Why you added setPlanDiscount and setBasePlanDiscount twice? that might be causing the issue, please check your code again.

Comment: No that is not the trouble. The line $total->addTotalAmount('plandiscount', -$discount); is adding the discount. If i comment everything except that line, then also discount will work.

Comment: I'm talking about this line : $quote->setPlanDiscount(-$discount);

Comment: i understand but that line is not creating trouble, i just checked removing as u said.

Comment: Please check my ans, hope it will help you to fix your issue.

Comment: @YashShah Have you figured out the solution? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @SarveshAhuja, Nope i didnt get any solution at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way to apply custom discount

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Mymodule\Model\Quote;
    class Discount extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
    {
     public function __construct(
     \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
     \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
     \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator $validator,
     \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     ) 
     {
     $this->setCode('testdiscount');
     $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
     $this->calculator = $validator;
     $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
     $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
     }

     public function collect(
     \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
     \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
     \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     )
     {
     parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
     $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
     $label = 'My Custom Discount';
     $TotalAmount=$total->getSubtotal();
     $TotalAmount=$TotalAmount/10; //Set 10% discount

     $discountAmount ="-".$TotalAmount; 
     $appliedCartDiscount = 0;

    if($total->getDiscountDescription())
     {
     $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
     $discountAmount = $total->getDiscountAmount()+$discountAmount;
     $label = $total->getDiscountDescription().', '.$label;
     } 

     $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
     $total->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
     $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
     $total->setSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
     $total->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getBaseSubtotal() + $discountAmount);

     if(isset($appliedCartDiscount))
     {
     $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
     $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
     } 
     else 
     {
     $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
     $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
     }
     return $this;
     }

     public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
     {
     $result = null;
     $amount = $total->getDiscountAmount();

     if ($amount != 0)
     { 
     $description = $total->getDiscountDescription();
     $result = [
     'code' => $this->getCode(),
     'title' => strlen($description) ? __('Discount (%1)', $description) : __('Discount'),
     'value' => $amount
     ];
     }
     return $result;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Not working, in any case $appliedCartDiscount returning 0.

Comment: I have added my code which I have used in one of my project and its working fine for me, so please try this way and let me know if any issue.

Comment: i applied your code and is working with default magento discount, but if i take it as seprate discount column, its not working.

Comment: as per your question you need to add custom discount code and now you asking for extra discount option right ?

Comment: yes, i checked and found that it is working fine in community edition. It is not working for EE only.

Comment: Ok, I have never worked in EE so I can't help you for EE sorry :)

Comment: Thats okay, thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @YashShah I think you should clarify everything in your question.